# ByteArrayOutputStream timeout

Tags: android, bytearrayoutputstream

I am downloading mp3 files to SD card. Sometimes when network connectivity is bad or internet is not available, ByteArrayOutputStream writes function keeps on running and even when the internet is available, the download does not resume. I want to throw timeout exception when the internet is lost but OutputStream doesn't provide a timeout mechanism natively. How to stop writing bytes when the internet is not available.
Below is code I am using -

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(downloadSongsList.get(count1).getTitle_Url());
    URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
    conection.setRequestProperty("Range", "byte  BHs=" + total + "-");
    conection.connect();
    //TODO: getting file length
    int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

    //TODO: input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);

    int bytesRead;
    data = new byte[lenghtOfFile];

    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(data)) != -1) {
        total += bytesRead;
        publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
        output.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
    }

    //encrypt = simpleCrypto.encrypt(ENCRIPT_DECRIPT_KEY, data);
    input.close();

    encriptFile(output.toByteArray());
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    success = "1";

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    success = "0";
    startTimer();
}
```

Comment: You analysed wrong. Writing to a byte array output stream has nothing to do with an internet connection. Please try again.

Comment: But, it is not giving any timeout exception if internet gets disconnected in between while downloading.

Comment: I do believe that. But what do you mean with `it` in `it is not giving..`. It is NOT the bytearrayoutputstream.

Comment: it refers to output.write in above code